# Is there a program like Microsoft Paint?

Tags: image-editor

I'm slowly getting used to Ubuntu; for I've been a Windows user as long as I've used any computer. I'm hoping someone can suggest a good graphics software.

I'm simply looking for one that works close to Microsoft Paint. (Paint brush functionality, simple paint operations, etc)
Does Ubuntu offer anything like it?

Comment: @Lucio That question is asking for editors that don't have tools like brush, pencil, erase, and so forth, and which are in effect mainly image viewers, with minimal editing functions like changing the image's orientation. This is quite different.

Comment: In my opinion, the other question address the requirements for a *MS Paint similar app*. Look at the accepted answers of both questions, they recommend the same app! But, as you say, someone might look for a different point of view. It is pretty tiny and subjective the difference here.

Comment: Shouldn't the other question be closed instead, if any? This question is older and more popular.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The current top answer may be Pinta for both questions, but that's because Pinta is a very versatile piece of software. The OP's intention is very different in the "duplicate" question.

Comment: I agree this is not a duplicate. And neither question should be closed - they definitely are different questions, not duplicates.. This one is looking for a simple application to do simple paint operations. I use Gimp, and I use Paint and they each serve very different cases.

Answer (score 367, accepted):

The closest MS Paint clone is [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/).  I regard it as vastly superior to MS Paint, but it retains its simplicity.

[image]

[image: Install via the software center]

**Edit**

On latest Ubuntu, you have to update permissions to avoid crash.[image]

1. Launch permission window from Software.
2. Enable the last permission
   "Read/Write files on removable storage devices."

Comment: +1 for Pinta, for newbies to linux its a better alternative than Gimp

Comment: +1 And it's modeled after Paint.NET! (And I've heard of it, too!)

Comment: +1, did what I wanted. Good screenshot btw - immediately tells you if this program is what you're looking for.

Comment: Does the ONE thing I can't do on GIMP... Make a stupid rectangle for censoring names (when I wanna post an auto-correct, etc)

Comment: @pgrytdal, you *can* draw rectangles on GIMP. I don't think it's as intuitive as it should, but this is how I do it: http://pbs01.wordpress.com/2007/09/30/145/

Comment: Thank god that you did not mention GIMP. I was looking exactly for an intuitive tool like Pinta. :-)

Comment: For me Pinta is much better than kolourpaint, xpaint and Gimp. It is easier, more intuitive and quite advanced.

Comment: +1 for Pinta. I'm a longtime MS Paint user. Struggled with both Gimp and ImageMagick on Ubuntu. I just installed Pinta. Took 5 minutes to install on Ubuntu 14.04 (sudo apt-get install pinta) and 5 minutes to figure out how to use. So far I've used it to copy, paste, erase, select colors, fill regions with color, and to draw rectangles, lines, ellipses and text.

Comment: It nearly dies on high resolution images.

Comment: text color is white and is not seen in white background, how to change text color?

Comment: Be careful, in pinta version before 1.5 (my ubuntu installed 1.3 by default) copy&paste is seriously bugged: for zoomed-in image the pasted rectangle appears off screen (in the corner of the image, not the screen). You have to add the pinta ppa manually to get newest stable version. That's the most important paint feature for me, so I nearly gave up pinta! (but the alternatives are not better :))

Comment: Pinta is too slow compared to good old Microsoft Paint.

Comment: I've always used KorourPaint.  It has all the functionality of MS Paint, with some functionality that I'd always missed having in MS Paint, like being able to insert text at any zoom level.   But it's simple and basic like MS Paint, and has the look and feel of MS Paint.

Comment: WARN! Doesn't work with Ubuntu 16.04, after start select area app is freezing and crash.

Comment: Not works with Ubuntu 18.04 - crashes when start image editing

Comment: Pinta is awful.  Try drawing a filled rectangle in two clicks.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Also, the performance problems that were a little bit concerning in HD cause serious problems in 4K.

Comment: In my little experience with pinta, It has no way to print/print preview file

Comment: Pinta is nowhere near a replacement for Paint. In addition to the other complaints here, here's another example: you can't even select a part of the image and resize it. You literally cannot resize a selection. There's been a push request since 2015. It's downright inaccurate to claim that Pinta is an MS Clone, much less that it's superior.

Comment: I don't see **edge smoothing** and **easy handling of transparency** which are two of my key requirements. Nice with the layers and the overall simplicity.

Comment: Pinta seems to constantly crash for me before I have even been able to make one edit to the image I open (I'm using Ubuntu Mate 18.04 LTS).

Comment: beware, Pinta depends on *mono* which is kinda big dependency for such a simple task. I chose [mtPaint](https://askubuntu.com/a/224630/16985) as it is more lightweight

Comment: not like MS Paint and too complicated.

Comment: This is ridiculous, it doesn't even show the image and selection size...

Comment: I found Pinta buggy and too complicated.  Gimp is far superior if I want a complicated editor.

Comment: it mostly crashes in Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 64):

For a basic MS Paint clone I would also suggest **[xpaint](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xpaint/)** and **[kolourpaint](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kolourpaint4/)**. Both are available on the Software Centre.

xpaint:
[image: xpaint]

kolourpaint:
[image: kolourpaint]

Comment: Kolorpaint is the most MS-Paint-like one I've found.

Comment: But its meant for KDE, right? Meaning tons of libraries downloaded in vanilla Ubuntu?

Comment: +1 for Kolorpaint. Too bad it drags with it a million KDE dependencies.

Comment: Sadly, xpaint looks nice but is absurd:  Things which are best done with keyboard are implemented mouse only.  Things which are best implemented with mouse are keyboard only.  Undo is very limited (why?).  Magnifier is modal (wtf?).  Not WYSIWYG (WTF!?!) when adding shapes.  etc. etc. etc.  sigh.

Comment: +1 for `kolourpaint`, too.  Easy to use, does the job, WYSIWYG, etc.  No quirks found yet.

Comment: Great product and simple, MS Paint replacement. To install, use `sudo apt-get install kolourpaint4`

Comment: @Tino xpaint is very old... it existed in the 80s. (probably not that version, but X-Windows came with an xpaint tool for a long time.)

Comment: +1 for KolourPaint! The first software I've tried that can do the extremely basic operations of selecting, moving a selection, deleting a selection and drawing lines properly and intuitively.

Comment: For some reason, though, KolourPaint messes up the color when you try to draw lines of thickness 1, and the lines becomes semitransparent. So either you have to draw thicker lines in order to make them get the correct color, or you have to use the fill tool and correct the color of the line after you have drawn it. Why?? Why can't there just be some program that can manage all the basic functions that exists in MS Paint without trying to be smart and as a consequence mess up some basic functionality? Sigh. (continued below)

Comment: KolourPaint is still the best simple drawing tool that I've tried, but I don't understand why it should be so difficult to make a good MS Paint clone.

Comment: this is the correct answer!

Comment: xpaint looks good, except for the lack of Undo.

Comment: +1 for kolourpaint too.  There's a slightly different mindset wrt filling a shape but it's pretty intuitive and sensible.  I like avoiding the complications of a fancy editor like Gimp for quick editing.

Comment: I'm using KolourPaint too. It's just straightforward in cases where I want to just highlight parts of a screenshot for example.

Comment: KolourPaint is the correct answer. It is lightweight and behaves extremely similar to MS-Paint from like 25 years ago.  MS-Paint has it's place, as does GIMP or xpaint. They are different tools with different purposes.

Answer (score 52):

There is also *Gnome Paint*.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Erm... "Sorry, but the zoom feature has not been implemented yet."

Comment: Erm... "Sorry, but the selection feature has not been implemented yet." up to 30 march 2014

Comment: Erm... Yea you get it, still not implemented.

Comment: Erm... "Sorry, but the text feature has not been implemented yet."

Comment: Copy&Paste not working either...

Comment: This looks like an MS Paint exact clone...except without many of the features implemented yet...still, as of 9 June 2016.  So, if you really want something simple and sweet to keep the kids entertained, KolourPaint is it! `sudo apt-get install kolourpaint4`

Comment: This is pure garbage. Dont go for it

Comment: *grumpy old man voice* It used to be part of the Gnome Human Interface Guidelines that you don't even bother to show users a button that doesn't work, or at-least disable it. a "this does nothing" popup used to be apropos and discouraged specifically.

Comment: Woah, guys. Gnome is open source. Go and submit a patch.

Comment: Guys, Ubuntu is open source, you haven't paid for it. Don't blame the authors as they have shared their work without getting any benefit. If you don't like it or want all features working, pay a license of a propietary operating system

Comment: Breaks when opening PNG files with transparency too. Absolute garbage.

Comment: Doesn't even have Undo / Redo !

Comment: @evilReiko well... it *says* it has Undo/Redo.  Not that it works.

Comment: You can't be like MS Paint if you don't have a rectangle tool.

Comment: Erm... "Sorry, but the text feature has not been implemented yet.

Answer (score 23):

[mtPaint](http://mtpaint.sourceforge.net/) is a lightweight equivalent of Microsoft Paint. It is lighter (requires only 1 MB to install because it depends on GTK which Ubuntu has out-of-the-box) than [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/), which needs 20 MB disc space on a standard Ubuntu install because of the Mono dependency.

mtPaint is documented, unlike Pinta: [mtPaint handbook](http://mtpaint.sourceforge.net/handbook/en_GB/chap_00.html)

Comment: available in the `mtpaint` package too

Comment: +1 for mtPaint.  Comes with Lubuntu, works just fine.

Comment: The people who write mtPaint should go join the Pinta team and improve Pinta.

Comment: the most lightweight yet usable alternative from all answers

Comment: Be aware quite a lot of features are missing - for instance I cannot find a way to draw a rectangle, there's only a freehand pencil tool for drawing.

Comment: How to draw circle/ellipsis in mtpaint?

Answer (score 14):

Ubuntu has GIMP in the default repositories. GIMP is far more powerful than Paint, but you needn't use all of its functions.

To install GIMP in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gimp
```

You just need an good introduction. At [Meet the Gimp](http://meetthegimp.org/) there are many, many comfortable video tutorials. It isn't easy to not get lost in the big number of options with gimp, but sooner or later you need more, than some simple program is offering, so it might be easier to learn one program in depth than first an easy one, and then the more complicated one too.

Comment: I find GIMP to be incredible hard to use if one wants only to draw shapes.

Comment: You're right, Georg: Gimp isn't easy. So I added a link to a collection of online-video tutorials to gimp.

Comment: Give it a try to start the gimp from the command line with --no-splash --no-data (and maybe some other option). Then it starts up faster (not the very first time, though), the GUI is less cluttered and it looks like a simple paint program.

Comment: Which gimp version do you need for that? With 2.6.8 I have nearly the same or the same UI, just the splash animation is missing.

Comment: You will need a weekend or so to get familiar with Gimp. It is not like Paint.

Comment: GIMP is great for highly complex modifications but this also overcomplicates its usage. For example, I don't need layers, and I just want a simple click-and drag copy/paste and resizing of the canvas. This is where a program like KolourPaint is amazing almost identical to MS-Paint.

Comment: Any paint program that requires a video tutorial TO DRAW A FILLED RECTANGLE has failed.

Comment: @breakpoint: You can draw filled rectangles with LibreOfficeCalc, LibreOfficeWriter,   gnuplot and many more. Most easy for that task is Inkscape, which is a vector drawing program and therefore not at all similar to Paint. But for using Inkscape, you need to understand the difference and its importance between objects and paths - if you get it, most things are easy to learn and understand. I guess in Gimp, which I don't know much about, there are basic principles to understand as well, which make the beginning hard.

Comment: Well, one problem for me, for example, is that there is a really important basic use case I need a DIRT SIMPLE solution for: redacting confidential data from screenshots before filing bug reports.  People aren't going to bother unless I can show them how to do it in a VERY short number of steps.  And all of these programs fail to do what you can, sadly, literally do in two steps in Microsoft Paint.

Comment: @breakpoint: It's a no brainer, if you use Inkscape.

Comment: @breakpoint I think the issue is rather that GIMP is not a _paint program_ but rather a kind of PhotoShop alternative. I agree that it should _not_ be recommended as a “program like MS Paint” because it is not.

Comment: Gimp is large and boots slowly. Definitely too heavy weight for simple tasks.

Comment: @Moberg When did you try the last time? It starts on my machine with a cheap and not that recent SSD in about 2 to 3 seconds. If you have to install your simple Graphics programm, first … - Gimp is very often installed by default.

Comment: @userunknown today, I don't want a several second load.

Comment: gimp is a fine tool, but it is not a simple paint program.

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch: I'm well aware, but what is your recommendation? Given, that I think that there isn't an equivalent for Paint, I made my recommendation and offered my rationale. What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 9):

Look at [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/), the feature rich screenshot tool. In Microsoft App terms, it is actually a combination of the snipping tool and ms paint.

It captures screenshots, but it also has an edit mode for the screenshots (or some file you can load from your hard drive) with some basic drawing tools, which are well thought-out and quite usable for inserting arrows and numbers into images, cropping, etc. Things you do to images to cut +paste them into presentations, after editing.

*Update 2021: These days, I would install Shutter from [Snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/shutter)*

Comment: Shutter has very nice features like cropping, annotation with text, arrows and shapes as well as blurring. Perfect for screenshots and also good for other purposes.

Comment: I've used shutter a lot for screenshotting, it's great for that, but it's not much like MsPaint when it comes to quick and simple drawing etc.

Comment: `snap info shutter`: `error: no snap found for "shutter"`

Comment: How to draw a rectangle? Seems to take many clicks. Also: how to export all of drawing to clipboard?

Answer (score 6):

It isn't Paint exactly but I really like Inkscape.  It is a vector graphics editor.

Maybe that is more than you want.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/inkscape/

Its also in the repository

Comment: InkScape is definitely the easiest and most powerful graphics program I've used, specially for drawing shapes and editing them. However, with my tablet, I sometimes need to scribble *text* and a dot is not easy to create. For example, when writing freehand text, suppose I want to write a lowercase 'i', the dot won't be visible. But then again, there are alternatives to it and still InkScape is my first choice.

Comment: InkScape is very powerful tool, I have been using that a lot.

Comment: Inkscape, as a vector drawing tool, as you mentioned yourself, is not 'not exactly Paint' - it's nearly as far from it, as a graphics program can be. The name isn't similar, the license isn't, the file formats aren't.