# Lightweight image-viewing app to slideshow images and animated gif in random order

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

I am trying to find the lightest possible image viewing program to perform a very specific task.

I have a large folder of images in various formats (jpg, png, gif). I want to view these images in a randomized order, either as a slideshow or scrolled through manually, with the animated gifs er, animating.

Thoughts?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/164473/simple-image-editor

Comment: The lightest possible image viewers (zgv, fim) don't even use X. Can you clarify if using X is acceptable or you need something that runs from the console? If X is OK, then the default (eog) image viewer should fit your purpose just fine.

Comment: stephen, I'm afraid not. I'm looking for a image viewer not an editor, and I have no idea hot shotwell can be used to view images in a randomized order, and I do not believe it works well with animated gifs.

Comment: roadmr, I am using X (gnome + xmonad). How could one use eog to perform the task?

Answer (score 0):

`feh` has the ability to display images in a random order using the `-z` flag, unfortunately however it cannot display animated gifs.

It is also extremely light and fast and can handle almost any file type.

[image: Install feh via the software center]

Comment: Yes, I like feh for all the reasons you've listed - but it falls for short for the reason you note ;)