# How to take screenshots with shutter while editor is open?

Tags: screenshot, shutter

I am using shutter to create screenshots.  The workflow that I would like to do is something like this:

1. Create a giant image 900x9000 px.
2. Open the image in the shutter editor
3. Take screenshots with the shutter screenshot tool and add them to my giant image.  I am currently documenting a bug that takes 10 different steps to reproduce, so I want to create a single screenshot containing the 10 steps.

Unfortunatly, this isn't working, because I need to close the shutter editor before I can grab more screenshots.

If I try to open a second instance of shutter, I get this:

```
[May-11 10:49][~]$ shutter
WARNING: Gtk2::AppIndicator is missing --> there will be no icon showing up in the status bar when running Unity!

INFO: There is already another instance of Shutter running!
```

I would accept answers any answers that allow me to keep an editor open while making more screenshots.  Options I have considered:

- Find a way to take screenshots from shutter while the editor is open
- Find a way to force shutter to open a second instance
- [Find another image editor with similar functionality to shutter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164473/simple-image-editor)
- Find another screenshot grabber and use shutter strictly for editing

I am using Shutter 0.93.1 rev 1278 on CentOs and Ubuntu.

Comment: I am not addressing your question at all, but if the bug takes 10 steps to be reproduced, why don't you just gif it? http://askubuntu.com/a/123515/29595

Comment: @dadexix86 - Interesting idea but I prefer step by step instructions, especially when the steps require detailed text steps.

Comment: many window-managers will take a screenshot when you press alt-shift-PrintScr.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a screenshot of terminal only then you can try this (I am not sure you are looking for this). You can run this command from a separate terminal and get the screenshot of your main terminal.

`import -windows    "<title_of_terminal>"     filename.png`

Generated image file will be saved under your home as : `~/home/filename.png`
PS-You can rename the terminal before using this for easy use. Don't forget the quotes for terminal title.

Also, you can check pre-assigned shortcuts for screenshots here and try:

`Settings > Keyboard > 'Shortcut' tab > 'Screenshot' menu item`

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using (and comfortable with) Shutter for editing, the simplest method might be to just use a different screenshot program to capture screenshots of your Shutter window. `kazam`, `gnome-screenshot`, `screenie-qt`, and `screengrab` are all in the Ubuntu software repositories and could accomplish this.

To install one of them using the command line, you can open a terminal (Alt+Control+T) and type

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install screenie-qt
```

(replacing `screenie-qt` with the name of whatever one you want to install)