# Ubuntu equivalent for Mspaint.exe?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-editor

What is the Ubuntu equivalent of Mspaint.exe? I need VERY BASIC image editing to make cheap comics or minor changes, creating memes, etc

Comment: See here http://askubuntu.com/questions/164473/simple-image-editor

Comment: Also see [Is there a program like Microsoft Paint?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36577/is-there-a-program-like-microsoft-paint)